# addEventListener (and removeEventListener) function that need param

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, createjs

I need to add some listeners to 8 object (palms).
These object are identical but the behaviour have to change basing to their position.
I have the follow (ugly) code:

```
root.palmsStatus = ["B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"];

if (root.palmsStatus[0] !== "N")
  root.game.palms.palm1.addEventListener("click", palmHandler = function(){ palmShakeHandler(1); });
if (root.palmsStatus[1] !== "N")
  root.game.palms.palm2.addEventListener("click", palmHandler = function(){ palmShakeHandler(2); });
if (root.palmsStatus[2] !== "N")
  root.game.palms.palm3.addEventListener("click", function(){ palmShakeHandler(3); });
if (root.palmsStatus[3] !== "N")
  root.game.palms.palm4.addEventListener("click", function(){ palmShakeHandler(4); });
if (root.palmsStatus[4] !== "N")
  root.game.palms.palm5.addEventListener("click", function(){ palmShakeHandler(5); });
if (root.palmsStatus[5] !== "N")
  root.game.palms.palm6.addEventListener("click", function(){ palmShakeHandler(6); });
if (root.palmsStatus[6] !== "N")
  root.game.palms.palm7.addEventListener("click", function(){ palmShakeHandler(7); });
if (root.palmsStatus[7] !== "N")
  root.game.palms.palm8.addEventListener("click", function(){ palmShakeHandler(8); });
```

I have two needs:

1) doesn't use an anonymous function on click event.

I wrote this code, but it doesn't work

```
root.game.palms.palm8.addEventListener("click", palmShakeHandler(8));
```

So this one works fine

```
root.game.palms.palm8.addEventListener("click", function(){ palmShakeHandler(8); });
```

But I didn't understand how remove the event listener.
I try this solution, but it doesn't work

```
root.game.palms.palm8.addEventListener("click", palmHandler = function(){ palmShakeHandler(8); });
root.game.palms.palm8.removeEventListener("click", palmHandler);
```

2) add and remove listener in a for cycle

I wrote the follow code but the behaviour is not correct.

```
  for (i=1; i <= root.palmsStatus.length; i++){
    if (root.palmsStatus[i-1] !== "N"){
      root.game.palms["palm" + i].addEventListener("click", function(){ palmShakeHandler(i); });
    }
  }
```

the listeners was added but the value of the parameter passed to the **palmShakeHandler** is always 8.

Nobody could help me to fix these issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a actually, a perfect way to do that in JavaScript using the `Function.prototype.bind` method.

`bind` let you define extra parameters that will be passed, as arguments, of the function.

You should also keep in mind that `bind` creates a new function and doesn't modify the initial function.

Here is what it looks like:

```
function palmHandler(number) {
  // your code working with `number`
}

var palmHandler8 = palmHandler.bind(null, 8)
// the palmHandler8 is now tied to the value 8.
// the first argument (here null) define what `this` is bound to in this function
```

This should fix your problem, and you will be able to remove handlers easily :)

Your code will look like this:

```
for (i=1; i <= root.palmsStatus.length; i++){
  if (root.palmsStatus[i-1] !== "N"){
    root.game.palms["palm" + i].addEventListener("click", palmShakeHandler.bind(null, i));
  }
}
```

To be able to remove the handler afterward, you need to keep a reference to the function you create with `bind`. This would be the way to do this.

```
var boundHandler = handler.bind(null, i);
element.addEventListener(boundHandler);
element.removeEventListener(bounderHander);
```

If you want to know more about the awesome `bind` method in JavaScript, the MDN is your friend :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

BTW, the problem with you function always returning `8` is a very common question in JavaScript. This thread will explain everything (spoiler, it's a matter of scoping :) ) https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/2745879

Comment: Adding listener into the cycle woks fine.
But removing them doesn't work

Comment: I use this code:
root.game.palms["palm"+palm].removeEventListener("click", palmShakeHandler);

Comment: Oh ok, to remove the handler, you need to keep a reference to the bound function and remove this one. `var boundPalm = palm.bind(null,i); addHandler(boundPalm) ... removeHandler(boundPalm)`

Comment: Awesome :) Welcome in the fabulous world of `bind` :D

Comment: If you are using EaselJS, you can also use the shortcut `on()`, which does binding for you, and takes a 3rd parameter (scope). http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/EventDispatcher.html#method_on

Answer (score 0):

In your last solution you are pasing the same var to every function and that is what make al the functions work with 8 because is the last value of the variable.

To work arround that you can use "let" ( please at least use var, otherside that "i" is global and can be changed every where in the code) but since I dont know wich browser you target I propose other solution.

```
for (var i=1; i <= root.palmsStatus.length; i++){
    if (root.palmsStatus[i-1] !== "N"){
      root.game.palms["palm" + i].addEventListener("click", (function(index)
      (return function(){ 
        palmShakeHandler(index); 
      }))(i);
    }
  }
```

Since its look like You are targeting modern browsers I will use let.https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

```
for (var i=1; i <= root.palmsStatus.length; i++){
    let index = i;
    let intermediateFunction = function(){palmShakeHandler(index);};
    if (root.palmsStatus[i-1] !== "N"){
      root.game.palms["palm" + i].addEventListener("click",intermediateFunction);
      root.game.palms["palm" + i].removeHandShake = function(){this.removeEventListener("click",intermediateFunction)};
    }
  }
```

So now you just need to call "removeHandShake" and will remove the listener,

I have code this right here so it ease some minor errors to pop

Comment: This seems a good solution, but I don't understand how remove the listeners added.

Comment: well since  you neeed the function reference to do the removeEventListener  you need to store it somewhere, I propose using a closure. Let me update the top answer

Answer (score 0):

So in case your array of »palms« is very huge, it is basically a bad Idea to add a single event listener to each of them, because that causes performance flaws. So I would suggest a different approach:

```
var handlers = [function (e) {}, …, function (e) {}];

root.game.palms.forEach(functiion (palm, idx) {
  palm.setAttribute('data-idx', idx);
});

<palmsparent>.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var c = e.target, idx = -1;

  while (c) {
    if (c.hasAttribute && c.hasAttribute('data-idx')) {
      idx = parseInt(c.getAttribute('data-idx'));
      break;
    }
    c = c.parentNode;
  }

  //here you also check for the »palm status«
  if (idx >= 0) {
    handlers[idx](c);
  }
})
```

One event listener for all, much easier to remove and better for performance.